# PHP simple operator logic

Tags: php, if-statement

This is really bothering me. I'm having trouble with some very very simple logic. A variable has to be between 5 and 35. If it is I want to print pass, if not print fail. I can't, for the life of me, get this to work. Its so simple...

```
    if($turboPressure > 5 && $turboPressure < 35) 
    {print "pass";}
    else
    {print "fail";}
```

Thats my latest attempt... I've tried like 4 different conditions and none have worked... Please help.

If anyone would like to look at it, I think you can view it at...
http://www.deltacst.net/php06/Lab4/Lab4.html

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the sample code.

Comment: What happens and what values are you trying it with?

Comment: Your conditional is fine (provided your definition of "between" is exclusive of the boundaries). If that doesn't work, `$turboPressure` isn't what you think it is. If `5` and `35` are supposed to be valid ("beetween" == inclusive of boundaries) you need to use `>=` and `<=`.

Comment: When the value is 6 it returns fail. When the value is 4 it returns fail.

Comment: Like nickb said, your code is perfectly fine. You must have done something wrong when defining $turboPressure

Comment: @JoshI:  [Works for me](http://codepad.org/0eri01E9).

Comment: @JoshI  How do you get the `$turboPressure`? Is it a string or an integer? show the result of `var_dump($turboPressure);`

Comment: add print $turboPressure; and see what it says

Comment: I just removed my answer about print vs. echo now you've said it does actually give you a value.

Comment: Alright I'll give that a shot.

Comment: `Print turboPressure;` didn't seem to return anything. I added the url to the post i you want to look at it.

Comment: `print $turboPressure;` not `print turboPressure;`

Comment: well, that's your problem. You've missed to define $turboPressure . If you could add the code where you're supposed to define it, we'll have a look

Comment: See my edit, you should use: `$turboPressure = intval( $_POST['turboPressure']);`

Comment: Sorry I did put print $turboPressure my bad.

Comment: wow really there is an accademy who teaches PHP ? Lovely

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. Here's proof:

```
foreach( range( 0, 40) as $turboPressure)
{
    echo $turboPressure . ' ';
    echo (($turboPressure > 5 && $turboPressure < 35) ? 'pass' : 'fail');
    echo "\n";
}
```

This loops through 0 to 40, printing either pass or fail with the same condition you wrote.

You might want to do:

```
$turboPressure = intval( $turboPressure);
```

This makes sure that you're dealing with integers instead of strings. If you're using strings, your comparison will fail.

The only tricky part of my sample is the [ternary operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php), which takes this:

```
if( condition)
    $var = 'something1';
else
    $var = 'something2';
```

And transforms it into

```
$var = (condition) ? 'something1' : 'something2';
```

[Watch it work.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/Lw16pa)

**Edit:**

Based on your sample code, you should get `$turboPressure` like so:

```
 $turboPressure = intval( $_POST['turboPressure']);
```

Comment: The form in the original html file (that is redirected to said php file on submit) has and input type of number... so I'm pretty sure is an integer value, not a string.

Comment: @JoshI - Not necessarily. You should use the last edit to retrieve the correct value from the POST data.

Comment: I think it worked. Let me finish up here...

Comment: @JoshI it doesn't really matter, $turboPressure = "25"; works just as good as $turboPressure = 25; .. Just make sure to define it ($turboPressure = $_POST['turboPressure'];) which you've obviously forgotten to do :)

Comment: Now when I print turboPressure, it returns a value of 0...

Comment: @JoshI - anyways, Nick's answer should work perfectly. +1

Comment: And I did put your `$turboPressure = $_POST['turboPressure'];` in

Comment: @JoshI - That's because you miss-spelled turboPressure in your HTML form. You've spelled it "tubroPressure"

Comment: Just keep in mind that the input is coming from the user, and that it does not have to be a string of integers... Thus `intval` ensures you're working with the correct data type.

Comment: Thanks @Tom... I hate misspellings...

Comment: true, but if it's not integers then it'll return false anyways, so doesn't really matter

Comment: FYI, `intval` without a numeric string input returns `0` `:)`

Comment: It all makes sense now. Chalk it up as a learning experience...

Comment: @nickb - and yeah, in other cases forcing integers might actually make a difference because of the 0, so good point. but in this case it wouldn't really matter

Comment: the ternary operator form isn't a good pratice to teach to newb. it deosnt' really help readabilty

Answer (score 0):

This works. Or actually should work. Perhaps you have mistyped something in the code part which you didn't show us. Please, give us the whole code (or at least the significant part). If it is log, try using pastebin.com.

Also, using echo instead of print is a good practice.

**IMPORTANT: `$turboPressure` does NOT automatically become `$_POST["turboPressure"]`, you have to add the line `$turboPressure=$_POST["turboPressure"];`**

Comment: I just checked the declarartion of the variables, and that's spelled right.

Comment: Anyway, this code piece does NOT help as the code works in itself.

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to cast your $turboPressure to int type first.

Anyway, you have to check the actual $turboPressure value. Not spelling. Not whatever *indirect* issue, but this very value itself, better using `var_dump()`

Answer (score 0):

This particular piece of code seems to working perfectly fine ... i have got an error log file from your server ( http://www.deltacst.net/php06/Lab4/error_log ) which shows the errors you have in your php code

on line 14 ( 3 errors ) 
on line 23 ( 2 errors )
on lie 31 ( 1 error )

check these line in your php file or reframe your question all the entire code of your php file this might help you